# How difficult is it to catch a taxi in Napa, California?

Tags: usa, taxis, california, northern-california

I would like to know if it easy/possible to get a taxi cab in Napa, California. A quick internet search brings up [Yellow Cab of Napa Valley](http://www.yellowcabnapa.com/).

But I'm wondering if anyone has had any experience with it. Is it easy to catch a ride/get a pickup (I just can't visualize how small/big Napa is)? And what prices should I expect for rides within the city or, say, to neighboring Yountville (7mi)?

Comment: In a small city like Napa, you'll probably have to phone the taxi company to request a pickup, rather than hailing a cab on the street.  You could call them and ask about fares, service area, etc.

Comment: Did you try talking to the Napa Chambers of Commerce? http://napavalley.com/visitorsinfo/chambersofcommerce.html

Comment: Your additional questions should be in a separate question - one question per post ([help])

Comment: @MarkMayo I agree, but the questions seemed to me very much tied to each other, making it an overhead to ask three separate questions for what is basically just one question: "How much does it cost to take a cab from Napa to Yountville?".

Comment: @MarkMayo In any case, hopefully the questions are simpler now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a shortage in Napa recently, and it's becoming [newsworthy](http://napavalleyregister.com/news/local/taxi-shortage-stifles-getting-about-napa/article_c26047fe-9987-11e2-9eee-001a4bcf887a.html):

> According to Crystal Britto, owner of Concierge of the Valley, getting
>   a cab in Napa on the weekends can be difficult. With only three main
>   taxi companies in town, riders have fewer choices for such
>   transportation, she said.

and

> Juliette Christensen, head concierge at Andaz Napa, said that during
>   busy times of the year it can be hard to get a cab in Napa. “Sometimes
>   it can be 30- to 45-minute wait,” she said.

The key 'problem' is the lack of a large enough community requirement for it, so they have to plan around seasonal variation:

> The need for taxis in Napa Valley is seasonal, he said. “Right now, we
>   run four to five cabs per shift instead of all 12.  During tourist
>   season we run 10 cabs minimum,” Bulger said.

so if a bunch of people need cabs at the same time, especially during off-season, you may have problems getting one, or at least a decent wait.

From [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g580460-i10025-k4192799-Cabs_in_Napa_plentiful_or_tricky-Napa_Valley_California.html) - some people wondered about getting taxis to take you around all the wineries in a day. The estimate there was $50-$80 per cab ride - presumably as they're not all that close together.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Yellow Cab of Napa unless the meter is ON.

Friday night my friend and I needed a taxi ride from Napa Wine train to Marriott in Vallejo.  A ride from the hotel to the wine train in a rush hour was $40 on the meter by a Vallejo taxi company.  Coming back we were quoted $65 flat rate by Yellow Cab of Napa once we were sitting in the car.  We discussed this rate with the driver, but the rate was take it or leave the car.

Scene: Downtown Napa, 10 pm, everybody else from the train already left and we were 2 two women in the dark in an empty parking lot.  Of course we were going to agree to any rate at this point!

Not a good way to do business!

Comment: B..b..b..but you didn't follow your own advice!